# Removing massive overhead from Git repository

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I have a local project in git, which contains some data (*e.g.* inputs for unit testing). This data has changed over the course of the project, and at one point was much larger. Now, I have no need of ever reverting the project to that state, but whenever I make perform a fresh `clone` with git, the size of the project is massive (from all of the data changes).

Is there a way to somehow reset my project to erase history in certain directories (*e.g.* project/data/) so that only the most recent state is stored?

Comment: Yikes. A few unnecessarily large `commit` and `push` executions, and a project can get pretty wrecked... Is there a way to completely reset the state of the project (it's worth it enough for me to just restart the project here).

Comment: You can use [`filter-branch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html) as a starting point.

Comment: Just curious: How bis is this project?

Comment: @KingCrunch Fetching the entire history with `clone` is in the GB range-- it contains code, LaTeX documentation, data, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To remove some files from the history but keep them in the most recent commits (e.g. the last 6 months), you can use `git filter-branch` as follows:

```
cutoff=`date -d '6 months ago' +'%s'`
remove="git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch 'project/data/*.zip'"
git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --index-filter \
  "[ `git log -1 --format=%at \$GIT_COMMIT` -lt $cutoff ] && $remove || true" \
  -- --all
```

To remove any leftovers after this, see [git filter-branch ­­– Checklist for Shrinking a Repository](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_checklist_for_shrinking_a_repository).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try `git gc --aggressive` just to clean up unreferenced items. If the big file changes were made within the last two weeks (by default), this won't get rid of them, but after enough time passes it should. This happens automatically, but you can force it with `git gc`

You can also change that two-week date by adding `--prune=now`, but that's **probably not a good idea** since you'd like to keep the history for most of your files.

Comment: Thanks. Will this affect the size of a fresh `clone` or simply pare down the disk space of my current checkout?

Answer (score 0):

If your collaborators won't be totally put out, just `cp` the directory somewhere while you're at the most downstream state, [`git filter-branch` the directory out of your codebase and cleanup after yourself,](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) then `cp` it back into the repo and commit it afresh.

Fair warning: Rewriting history is not to be engaged in lightly, but if it's just you, or a few collaborators who all know what they're doing, it's not that big a deal if it significantly improves your day-to-day life.